# Fastest way to load 50Gb of Relational Data into Virtuoso?

Tags: bulkinsert, virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I have a relational table with schema `(id, numvalue1, numvalue2, name, surname, telephone)`. The first three columns are `integer` and the last three columns are `nvarchar`.

Loading 1 million records into Virtuoso now takes around 5-6 hours with batch insert.

Is there a more efficient way to load large files of relational data into Virtuoso (as bulk insert for RDF data)?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Virtuoso documentation for SQL bulk load](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/sqlbulkloadoperationsftable/)  (and following page)? If that doesn't serve, please provide more detail -- where is your data starting from? Have you tuned Virtuoso settings to [use available system resources](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfperfgeneral/)? What version of Virtuoso are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your comment but "Virtuoso documentation for SQL bulk load" is not the case for me as I want to update my database. I tried csv_load, csv_load_file(http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_csv_load/) based on the code they provide but I get always an error either for the access in the .ini file or for the parametrs of the functions or for the table name.

Comment: There's not enough information here to usefully advise you. I suggest you raise your issue on the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), or if you're using the Commercial Edition, in a [Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figure out the answer I was looking for. There is the csv_load function (see http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtCsvFileBulkLoader). Most versions do not have it pre-installed so you have to write the given script in the isql console. The script has a typo in the array definition ("arr") instead of type "ANY", the type is "any".